# Scraping and submitting a form via Mechanize. How do I see the parameters passed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mechanize, charles-proxy

I'm scraping an Amazon form and submitting it. When I submit the form via my code, it bounces me back to that same form with no errors but clearly something is going wrong. My hunch it's either an SSL thing or no `session_id`.

Regardless, I'd like to inspect the POST request to see what it looks like and compare it to what [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com) returned when I did the request via the UI in my browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just proxy the request through Charles:

```
agent.set_proxy 'localhost', 8888
```

You'll probably also need to:

```
agent.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
```